# NHibernate - Sqlite in memory DB - Can't test the mapping files

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I wanted to test whether my entities can be persisted to the database or not, so I came across this article:

http://www.codethinked.com/nhibernate-20-sqlite-and-in-memory-databases

My code to initialize the session factory is the same the one in the article:

```
public class NHibernateInMemoryTestFixtureBase
{
    protected static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected static Configuration configuration;

    public static void InitalizeSessionFactory(params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        if (sessionFactory != null)
            return;

        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        properties.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver");
        properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect");
        properties.Add("connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
        properties.Add("connection.connection_string", "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;");
        properties.Add("connection.release_mode", "on_close");

        configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Properties = properties;

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            configuration = configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);
        }
        sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public ISession CreateSession()
    {
        ISession openSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        IDbConnection connection = openSession.Connection;
        new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(false, true, false, true, connection, null);
        return openSession;
    }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
[Test]
public void IWillChangeThisNameLater()
{
    InitalizeSessionFactory(typeof(LogRepository).Assembly);

    var session = this.CreateSession();

    Log log = Log.New("a", "b", "I");

    session.Save(log);
    session.Flush();

    Assert.Greater(log.IDColumn, 0);
}
```

And the problem is, I removed the "a" property of Log from the log.hbm.xml and session.Save(log) is not throwing an exception or anything, it just works...

This must be obvious and on porpose, but I fail to find out why that is, how can it save it if is not mapped, is that how the in memory database work? how can I test my mapping then?

I mainly did this in-memory test so that I can know right away if a valid entity is failing to persist, of course that would include missing properties on the mapping file.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

As requested,

the Log entity definition:

```
public class Log : DomainBase<Log, ILogRepository<Log>>
{
    private int logId;
    private string tableName;
    private string field;
    private string userLogin;

    protected Log()
    {
    }

    protected Log(string tableName, string field, string userLogin)
    {
        TableName = tableName;
        Field = field;
        UserLogin = userLogin;
    }

    public virtual int LogId { get; set; }
    public virtual string TableName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Field { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserLogin { get; set; }
}
```

the Log Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="DomainProject" table="Log" lazy="true">
    <id name="logId" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="TableName" column="TableName" type="string" />
    <property name="Field" column="Field" type="string" />
    <property name="UserLogin" column="UserLogin" type="string" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Is the "a" property mapped (well, not mapped) to nullable column? Or are you saying that there is at the end value in column "a"?

Comment: Yes, and I guess that is why I'm not getting an exception... but still the property's value is "a" after I call save, so I don't really understand know how nhibernate can assign the value

Comment: Could you, please, show your Log definiton and mapping. As Oskar said: NHiberante ignores unmapped properties. That's the fact. So it cannot be NHibernate who inserts into unmapped column...

Comment: Sure, sorry that I didn't do it in the first place, please check the update!

Comment: So this is mapping. It looks very well. It even even maps "TableName" and persist that, right?. And the issue is that if you comment/remove the TableName mapping, column `TableName` is inserted with the "a" string?

Comment: exactly, but I guess I know what the problem is... NHibernate is simple ignoring it, since I passed the "a" value in the entity constructor, it SEEMS like "a" is persisted, but it is just there because I assigned it on the Log creation, since I'm in memory, I don't really know how to test if it was persisted or not other than checking if my identity column got updated, u got me?

Comment: Call Session.Flush(), Session.Clear() then `Session.Get<Log>(rememberedId)`... you will se if the TableName is assigned. And then you can test, that "a" was not persisted ;)

Comment: I did exactly as you told me, and guess what? a is there!! and it shouldn't be, right?!

Comment: No! It should not. And (I am almost sure;) it cannot, if persisted by NHibernate. The issue is that I do not know the in memory DB. But it seems that in this case, the entity is simply still referenced. Persisted in memory as a reference. Not a record in in-memory table. That's only way how I can take it... really cool what you found, and played with ;)

Answer (score 0):

If a class contains a property that is not mentioned in the mappings, NHibernate will ignore the property.